# Why doesn't this work with the jQuery animate function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, slice, parseint

```
var pieceSize = new Array();
pieceSize[0] = 200;
pieceSize[1] = 400;
pieceSize[2] = 300;
```

**THIS DOESN'T WORK:**

```
$("#visual").animate({
        height: pieceSize[this.id.slice(5, 6)]
    }, 250, function() {
    });
```

**BUT THIS DOES:**

```
$("#visual").animate({
        height: pieceSize[2]
    }, 250, function() {
    });
```

**LOG:**
this.id.slice(5, 6) == 0 or 1 or 2 (i'm slicing the id of the button being clicked)

I've tried different combinations adding parseInt and none of it works:

height: `pieceSize[parseInt(this.id.slice(5, 6))])`

height: `parseInt(pieceSize[this.id.slice(5, 6)])`

height: `parseInt(parseInt(pieceSize[this.id.slice(5, 6)]))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just working: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mikey/Lfyvr/)

What is in the log if you echo `pieceSize[this.id.slice(5, 6)]`?

Comment: logs as 300 outside the function but undefined inside... didn't realize 'this' would refer to #visual

Comment: Yes it does because you are in the animate function scope

Answer (score 2):

this in your case will fetch the id "visual".  is the id of the button also "visual"??

Comment: ahh i see... nope, my button has a different id (button0, button1, etc.)